# Parse binary in Erlang

Tags: http, parsing, binary, erlang

If I have the following binary: `<<"GET http://www.google.com HTTP/1.1">>`, how can I split it up so that I can retrieve only the host (`http://www.google.com`) ?

I started with something like:

`get_host(<<$G, Rest/binary>>) -> get_host(Rest);

get_host(<<$E, Rest/binary>>) -> get_host(Rest);

get_host(<<$T, Rest/binary>>) -> get_host(Rest);`

but I am not sure how to go on from here. I was thinking of reversing `Rest` and starting over from the end of the binary.

Comment: Well, why try? is it stream and not a fixed binary? (Like you don't now when the GET will show up). Otherwise split the binary.

Comment: http://wagerlabs.com/parsing-text-and-binary-files-with-erlang?c=1

Comment: @Jonke: it's actually the binary coming out of a browser's request; the above binary is only a small part of all the headers that a browser sends.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems you're trying to implement a minimal parser for [HTTP 1.1](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html). This is [one solution](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#decode_packet-3) that does follow the specifications for HTTP 1.1 and parses the first line of a http request. Without knowing your specific situation I would in most cases recommend using a generic HTTP parser before a simplified "split binary" or similar.

```
1> erlang:decode_packet(http,<<"GET http://www.google.com HTTP/1.1\n">>,[]).  
{ok,{http_request,'GET',
              {absoluteURI,http,"www.google.com",undefined,"/"},
              {1,1}},
<<>>}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend `erlang:decode_packet` for this, but to show how it can be done, here is a pair of functions that strips the leading `"GET "` and then returns everything up to the first space (but crashes if there is no space).

```
get_host(<<"GET ", Rest/binary>>) ->
    get_host2(Rest, <<>>).

get_host2(<<" ", _/binary>>, Acc) ->
    Acc;
get_host2(<<C, Rest/binary>>, Acc) ->
    get_host2(Rest, <<Acc/binary, C>>).
```

Basically, I put each byte that is not a space into my "accumulator", and when I find the space I return my accumulator.  This is a common trick that is more often seen with lists.  (With lists you will want to put new items at the *front* of the list and reverse the list at the end, to avoid your O(N) algorithm turning into O(N²), but that is not needed for binaries.)

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer (but probably not what you really is asking for)

```
B = <<"GET http://www.google.com HTTP/1.1">> .
{_,H}=split_binary(B,4). 
split_binary(H,21).
```